# how to store objects in one array in common controller whose objects attribute are set from two different forms

Tags: angularjs

```
sampleApp.controller('maincontroller',function($scope,$rootScope){      
    $rootScope.person=[];   
})   

sampleApp.controller('AddPersonalDetails',['$scope','myService',function($scope,myService,$rootscope) {

      $scope.addData=function(){
        // $scope.data.pname=data.name;
         $scope.person.push($scope.data);
  console.log(person);  
     }     

}]);


sampleApp.controller('AddEducationalDetails', ['$scope','myService',function($scope,myService,$rootscope) {

    $scope.addMydata=function(){

        $scope.person.push($scope.data); 

     }           
}]);
```

i want to add objects attribute from different controllers as data and want to store in single object and that object store in array of person in main controller ..

common controllr -- add data.name
personal controllr -- add personl details
educatinal controllr -- add educational details..

help me out to sort this problem

Comment: Can you format the code aspect of your question correctly? Its difficult to read.

Comment: And where is the code for your service?

Comment: im not using service yet ... im using $rootScope but if u can do with that then thnx in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Angular's value service to register an app wide property.

e.g.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.value('person', []);
```

Then use it in, for example, a controller:

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'person', function($scope, person) {
    // Do something to get some data
    person.push($scope.data);
}]);
```

Note that you need to pass the value in as a dependency for your controller.

**UPDATE**

It sounds like you want to update the same data object from different controllers on the same page. In this case, you can use a factory to initialise and then return **the same** data object to each controller. You'll need to pass the factory service into each controller as a dependency.

This way, both your AddPersonalDetails and your AddEducationalDetails controllers can add the same data object to their scopes for adding/updating data.

**Factory**

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .factory('DataService', [function() {

        var data = {};

        return data;

    }]);
```

**AddPersonalDetails controller**

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('AddPersonalDetails', ['$scope', 'DataService', function($scope, DataService) {

        $scope.data = DataService;
        // Could also set some properties from this controller
        // e.g. $scope.data.name = 'Chris';

    }]);
```

**AddEducationalDetails controller**

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('AddEducationalDetails', ['$scope', 'DataService', function($scope, DataService) {

        $scope.data = DataService;
        // Could also set some properties from this controller
        // e.g. $scope.data.college = 'Harvard';
    }]);
```

Then when you want to push to your person array:

**MainController**

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('MainController', [
        '$scope',
        'DataService',
        function($scope, DataService) {
            $scope.persons = [];
            $scope.data = DataService;

            $scope.saveChanges = function() {
                // Make a copy of the data object, otherwise you'll be trying to save
                // the same object over and over
                var newData = angular.copy($scope.data);
                $scope.persons.push(newData);
            }
        }
    ]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="AddPersonalDetails">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="data.name">
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-controller="AddEducationalDetails">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="college">College</label>
        <input id="college" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="data.college">
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveChanges();">Save Person</button>
    <h1>People</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="person in persons">
        <p>Name: {{person.name}}</p>
        <p>College: {{person.college}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've created a plunk for you here so you can test and play around with it. Hopefully this is what you're after.

http://plnkr.co/edit/5CCskS?p=preview

Comment: thnx for ur answer But my actual problem is that data is an object here and its atrribute are collected from different controllers (like personal controller has its name ,address and educatiional controller has degree or board ) and i want to set this attribute for single object first as in data and then push into an array i.e person ....person is shared that is Ok but how to make object with these attributes coming from different controllers ...

Comment: So person should be an object then and not an array? And you want to set properties for person from different controllers?

Comment: nooo..... hmm its look like this person=[] and data={}   and i want to add proterties into data as data={name:" ",email:" ",education:" ",college:" "} and here name and email come from controller and other are form different controller and finally want push that data object into person array..like    [{name:"",email:"",edu:"",college},{name:"":....}]....no of objcts for diffent diff user info into person[]

Comment: if u got my problem then plz me sol with using services or factry coz i tried with rootscope but not effiecient

Comment: Ok, and are all of these controllers on the same page?

Comment: thnk you :) i'll run ..thnx a lot -chris

Comment: Great news :)

Could you please accept this answer as the one that worked for you? Thanks.